# Identification: Is this really a case of Progeria?

Tags: human-biology, pathology

There are some news about a boy being born in Bangladesh that looks very aged and presumably has Progeria: http://metro.co.uk/2016/09/29/newborn-baby-who-looks-like-an-80-year-old-after-being-born-with-rare-ageing-condition-6159215/

To my knowledge, humans born with Progeria looks quite normal at first, and it's not until after birth that the associated symptoms start to develop.

Is it plausible that this actually is a case of Progeria? Is there any other syndrome that would better match the appearance of the boy?

Comment: Not that it matters, but it appears the baby was born in Bangladesh.

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor Thank you, I've corrected it.